# seeking suggestion on datatypes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

may anyone suggest which could be best datatype for data like this.

```
2/26/2016  3:25:57 PM
```

Comment: `DATETIME2` (if you're using SQL Server **2008** or newer)

Comment: For reference: [datetime2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks Marc....

Comment: @JonathonOgden: Thanks Jonathon

Comment: @marc_s Why not answer?  This is going to be in limbo until someone copies your comment and it gets accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a date and a time combined (with no timezone information, as far as I can see), I'd recommend using

```
DATETIME2
```

as your data type. It's more accurate and more efficient than `DATETIME`, and it's available as of SQL Server **2008** and newer.

[Here's the detailed MSDN documentation on it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx)